Using Python win32com.client to import Word document HEADINGS (not Headers)
I have a grand total of 3 weeks of very part time experience with Python
This is close as I have gotten with somebody else's code
import win32com.client

def iter_headings(paragraphs):
    for paragraph in paragraphs:
#The code crashes on the next line!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        if paragraph.Style.Name.startswith('Heading'):
            yield paragraph


# Create a Word application instance
word = win32com.client.Dispatch('Word.Application')

# Open the Word document
document = word.Documents.Open('d:\\header.docx')

# Access paragraphs using the Document object
for heading in iter_headings(document.Paragraphs):
    print(heading.Text)

# Close the Word document (optional)
document.Close()
word.Quit()`

Any ideas to help would be welcome!  I am also using win32com.client to read in the contents of multiple tables in the document and that is working well in another test file, so I would prefer to stick with with win32com if possible.
See the above code.

What is your question? If you're asking about a specific error (as the comments seem to suggest), please include a full stacktrace for the error.

From the errors, you'll be able to tell that it can't find .Name and that's because you want .NameLocal and the next error will be on .Text because you're missing .Range.Text - read the error messages and use either a debugger, dir(), or the documentation to make sure you are using the right components and attributes.
